# Errors in file reading in binary mode with language C

Tags: c, io

I do exercice of 'c primer plus' chapter 13.10-4:
**Write a program that accepts no or one command line argument. If there is one, interpret it as a filename; if there is no argument, use standard input (stdin) as input. Assume the input is a floating point number. The program is to calculate and report the arithmetic mean of the entered numbers.**

> result

The part of standard input can work well when excecute visual studio, but when write and read the file with cmd, average value is "nan"
[image]

> enviroment

I use win10, le latest version of Visual Studio

> code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double ch;
    double numbers[12];
    FILE* fp;
    double average=0;
    int i = 0;
    if (argc==1)
    {
        printf("enter double, end with q\n");
        while (scanf_s("%lf", &ch))
        {
            average += ch;
            printf("%lf\n", ch);
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
            numbers[j] = 10.1 * j;
        fopen_s(&fp, argv[1], "wb");
        fwrite(numbers, sizeof(double), 10, fp);
        fclose(fp);
        if ((fopen_s(&fp, argv[1], "rb")!=0))
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"cant find %s\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }           
        while (fseek(fp, (long)i * sizeof(double), SEEK_SET)!=0)
        {
            fread(&ch, sizeof(double), 1, fp);
            fprintf(stdout, "ch\n");
            average += ch;
            i++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    printf("average is %lf\n", average/i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `fseek` in the loop? The read position will be advanced automatically when you read from the file.

Comment: Why not test if `fread` actually read the bytes you asked it to... Maybe at EOF it stopped reading, until you had fseek try to go beyond the end of the file.... Weird...

Comment: No problem if you replace the unnecessary `while(fseek...` and `fread` with `while (fread(&ch, sizeof(double), 1, fp) == 1)`

Comment: check return values from fopen, fwrite, fread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong test for `fseek()` with

```
while (fseek(fp, (long)i * sizeof(double), SEEK_SET)!=0)
```

The [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64?view=msvc-170) states

> **Return Value**.
> If successful, `fseek` and `_fseeki64` returns 0.

But even if you change `!=0` to `==0` it is still wrong, because the man page also says

> The pointer can also be positioned beyond the end of the file.

Because file reads are sequential, you can simplify the loop to

```
while (fread(&ch, sizeof(double), 1, fp) == 1)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "ch\n");
    average += ch;
    i++;
}
```

You also omitted the essential check for file input: the return value from `fread()` was ignored.